# How to check if the submitted picture is horizontal? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom validation rule by using the command:
`php artisan make:rule Horizontal`

Now, how to check if the submitted picture from my post form is horizontal?
I tried this:

```
 public function passes($attribute, $value)
{

    if ($this->request->has('picture')) {
        $image = $this->request->get('picture');
        if ($image->width < $image->height) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Image must be horizontal!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public function message()
{
    return 'The validation error message.';
}
```

My Post Request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'body' => 'required|min:10',
        'picture' => [
            'required',
            new Horizontal()
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t actually confirm a picture is landscape, only that it’s width is greater than it’s height. I could add a portrait image to a landscape canvas and it would validate.

Answer (score 0):

After Image upload
[Laravel Intervention Image](https://image.intervention.io/v2) Can help like this:

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

$img->flip('h');
```

**h** for horizontal and **v** for vertical.

There is one more method **orientate** to set auto Orientation as well

You can compare height and width as well

This image library required **GD library** and **Imagick** plugin

Good luck!